# Doubt on a question involving Euler's Theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, homogeneous-equation

I came across a question where I had to apply Euler's theorem on a function U(x,y) which is represented in terms of f(y/x), g(y/x) and another expression in terms of x and y. The question is as follows:

If $$u(x,y) =  \frac{(x^2+y^2)^n}{2n(2n-1)}  + x f(\frac{y}{x})+g(\frac{y}{x}),$$ where f and g are arbitrary functions, prove by using Euler’s theorem that

$$\Bigl(x\frac{∂}{∂x}+y\frac{∂}{∂y}\Bigr)^2u(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^n.$$

I wrote the first expressions as $$x^{2n}h(\frac{y}{x}),$$
expanded the square term, and tried to get the result, but in vain. I'm not sure if this is the right method and I messed up the calculation.

Any inputs on how to proceed would be really helpful. Kindly refrain from providing the actual answer. Thank you!

Edit: Another input would be that the sum of two homogeneous functions need not be homogeneous. How do we then apply Euler's Theorem?

Comment: Which Euler's theorem are you talking about? There any many results attributed to Euler.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been specific...I'm referring to the following theorem: If u=f(x,y) is a homogeneous function of degree n, then $$x\frac{∂u}{∂x}+ y\frac{∂u}{∂y}=nu$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing as an answer instead of a comment because use of pictures. Basically this is just a lot of algebra. Expand your operator as
$$x^2\partial^2_x+xy\partial_x\partial_y+y^2\partial^2_y$$
And take the partial derivatives. Not bothered to do the algebra by hand, I checked using Mathematica, and the result is correct:

[image]

Comment: So, how do you write the differential f(y/x) and g(y/x)??

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar It's simple, e.g $f'(y/x)\cdot \partial_x\{y/x\}.$

Comment: Oh yes, I missed out on the chain rule thats probably where I went wrong...Thank you so much!!